# Wi-Fi: Connected but no internet after sleep

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10

I use a shared, open Wi-Fi network to get internet access for my laptop. I have no problems connecting to the network or using the internet. However, when I take my laptop out of sleep mode, I am no longer able to use the internet **even though I still appear to be connected** to the network just fine:

[image: No internet, open]

To work around this issue, I have to disconnect and reconnect to the network after which I am able to access the internet again. I have not had this problem with any other networks.

Is there a solution to this problem? I realize this may be an issue with the network rather than the OS or my laptop, but even so: is there a way to work around this?

I'm using Windows 10 on a Dell XPS 9550.

Comment: Sounds like the power saving options could be failing to awaken the WiFi radio correctly when coming out of sleep. Have a check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928152).

Comment: I don't think it's a radio issue because it only happens with this specific network.  I have played around with power settings but it does not change anything.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the network saw no activity on the connection for long enough that it decided to drop the connection from its end?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue by putting my laptop to sleep and immediately turning it back on, making a timeout unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this problem was caused by having the Windows 10 feature "Random hardware addresses" enabled. Disabling this feature resolved the issue.